# How to prove the Lorenz Equations are in steady state at the origin

Tags: fluid-dynamics

The Lorenz equations are described as:

> $\dfrac{dx}{dt} = -\sigma x + \sigma y$
>   $\dfrac{dy}{dt} = (r-z)x - y$
>   $\dfrac{dz}{dt} = xy - bz$

I’m looking to prove that these are in steady state at the origin
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You didn't define all your variables. What is your work?

Comment: If $x = y = z =0$, the derivatives are all zero.